# How to display only date instead of datetime format from mysql to frontend javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

[enter image description here][1]In MySql database, the column DOB uses the data type `"date"`. But when Javascript displays the contents of that, it shows datetime format (i.e.  instead of `"1993-02-02"`, it displays `"1993-02-01T18:30:00.000Z"`.)
So please suggest solutions for this.

> var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>   var mydata = xhttp.responseText;
>   mydata.forEach(function (element) {
>   var myTable = "" + element.DOB
>   +"/td>"+"/tr>";
>    $(".mytable").append(myTable);
>   });

following image is database table image showing correct date format
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOaCy.png"

following image is frontend image showing dtae with time format."https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShZaU.png"

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: show your code which help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this code
-----------   

var date = new Date("1993-02-01T18:30:00.000Z"); 
var dates = date.toDateString();
var datess = dates.split(' ');     
if(date.getMonth()+1>=10) {
return datess[2]+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3]+' '+date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].slice(0,5);
} else {      
return datess[2]+'-'+'0'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3]+' 
'+date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].slice(0,5);
}
```

Comment: Mr. Raja , Here i am not creating an object. I am just fetching DOB from database and showing on frontend. and at frontend i m getting date with time.So suggest something to convert that fetched datetime format to date format.

Comment: Create one java script function and script function.like function dateformat (dob) {   var date = new Date(dob); 
var dates = date.toDateString();
var datess = dates.split(' ');     
if(date.getMonth()+1>=10) {
return datess[2]+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3]+' '+date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].slice(0,5);
} else {      
return datess[2]+'-'+'0'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datess[3]+' 
'+date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].slice(0,5);
}  }   . var myTable = "" +dateformat(element.DOB) +"/td>"+"/tr>";
$(".mytable").append(myTable);

Comment: Thanks Mr.Raja Ramachandran.

Answer (score 0):

You could either format this on the client side using a library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), or you could format the date as a string as part of your select statement.  In MySQL the syntax would be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM mytable AS dob;
```